# How to do Partition for mysql Hierarchy Table structure

Tags: mysql, location, partitioning

I am building a classifieds website. Can you suggest me how do I 
partition geolocation table based on country ???

**UPDATE:** Can I do based on latitude and longitude ?

Below is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geo` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `location_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT,
 `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'parent location_id',
 `latitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `longitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT '0:visible,1:invisible'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

(This is an un-answer.)

Do not `PARTITION` for the heck of it.  There is rarely any performance gain, nor coding convenience.

If you want to do any arithmetic with `latitude` and `longitude`, don't use `VARCHAR`, use something numeric.  `FLOAT` is precise enough for 1.7m (5.6 ft).

Further discussion of partitioning, including the only 4 uses:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .

What is the 'hierarchy' for?

Comment: Thanks. Will I paritition based on latitude / longitude ?

Comment: Again, partitioning won't necessarily help you.  Let's see the queries you intend to run.